# What are FP-growth allowed input data type?

Tags: c#, database, sequence, data-mining, text-mining

I would like to mine frequent pattern from my data. My dataset is however very large. First I need to transform it into transaction database format. The thing is that In my database (of 500000 records), there are 402 unique repeating items. Everywhere I see fp-growth examples with dataset of max 8 characters (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H), however I need to represent 402 unique items. Can I use combination of alphabetical characters for this algorithm? Or are there any other approaches?
Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your implementation.

But it's fairly standard to allow items such as 'milk' and not only one letter items.